# No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction'

Tags: android, xml, android-menu

I have the following error when trying to implement an Action Bar in my project. 
I do not know enough about Action Bar, someone could give me some help link

My Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidaz.scanner"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
         android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name" 
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My menú

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title=""/></menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build target should be Honeycomb in order to use showAsAction.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
```

Comment: Edit and error : Description Resource Path Location Type
Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output. scanner  line 1 Android ADT Problem

Answer (score 5):

Please try remove this,

> android:showAsAction="never"

from **res/menu** folder from every xml file.